# Sort table by last name/second name using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Below is my table

```
  <table id="sorting">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Ann Smith</td>
        <td>Ball Clever</td>
        <td>Cat Work</td>
         <td>Deer Run</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the sorting to be applied on the lastname/second name and display the output as follows:

```
<table id="sorting">    
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Ball Clever</td>
            <td>Deer Run</td>        
            <td>Ann Smith</td>      
            <td>Cat Work</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Any suggestions. I want this to be done using a JQuery.

Comment: Do you have code? One that you probably tried?

Comment: you need to show us what you've tried

Comment: Would this account for pagination because if so then you don't want to use front end to sort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean for each cell to be it's own row, not that you're trying to sort a row, in which case I would recommend using [this Tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) with a custom `textExtraction` function, something like: `$(x).text().split(' ').reverse()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items.sort(function(a, b){
    if($(a).html().split(' ')[1] < $(b).html().split(' ')[1]) return -1;
    if($(a).html().split(' ')[1] > $(b).html().split(' ')[1]) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jbg8gr3x/1/

Comment: Hi, this didn't work as sort function cannot be used on a non array object. my html looks like  <table id="sorting">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <li>>Ann Smith</li>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <li>Ball Clever</li>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <li>Cat Work</li>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <li>Deer Run</li>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

Answer (score 0):

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  console.log(a)
  var splitA = a.innerHTML.split(" ");
  var splitB = b.innerHTML.split(" ");
  var lastA = splitA[splitA.length - 1];
  var lastB = splitB[splitB.length - 1];

  if (lastA < lastB) return -1;
  if (lastA > lastB) return 1;
  return 0;
}

var names = $('td');

var sorted = names.sort(compare);
$('#sorting tr').html(sorted)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sorting" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Ann Smith</td>
      <td>Ball Clever</td>
      <td>Cat Work</td>
      <td>Deer Run</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort()` JS method on the jQuery collection of `td` elements and then use `.html()` to add the sorted cells to their parent `tr` element.

```
$('#sorting tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).html( $(this).find('td').sort(function(a,b) {
        return $(a).text().split(' ')[1] < $(b).text().split(' ')[1] ? -1 :
        $(a).text().split(' ')[1] > $(b).text().split(' ')[1] ? 1 : 0;
    }) );
});
```

If you actually wanted each cell to be in it's own row, a slight modification of the the code would work with the right HTML.

```js
$('#sorting tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).html( $(this).find('td').sort(function(a,b) {
        return $(a).text().split(' ')[1] < $(b).text().split(' ')[1] ? -1 :
        $(a).text().split(' ')[1] > $(b).text().split(' ')[1] ? 1 : 0;
    }) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table id="sorting">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Ann Smith</td>
        <td>Ball Clever</td>
        <td>Cat Work</td>
         <td>Deer Run</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```